# WebStorm 2018.3 editor background colour

Tags: colors, menu, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have spent a good couple of hours configuring WebStorm the way I like it, but for the life of me, I can't find the setting to configure the background colour of the editor, for TypeScript and other types of files.

There are lots of posts about this on stackoverflow, but they either pertain to previous versions or just don't work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction in the preferences? I am running Mac OS X and WebStorm 2018.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the background color of **Text | Default text** in **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General**:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the colours of the project pane? It seems not...

Comment: No; it's defined in Look&Feel (UI theme) and thus hardcoded. we’re working on a feature allowing themes customization in IntelliJ Platform. Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132299 to get updates.